# Combine data.table transformations in one line

Tags: r, data.table

I have written a data.table data transforming code:

```
table_patterns <- table[, pattern := stringr::str_extract(LOG_MSG, "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+")]
table_patterns <- table_patterns[, pattern := coalesce(stringr::str_extract(pattern, "^create new|regulate values"),pattern)]
table_patterns <- table_patterns[, system_type := case_when(class%in% c("class1", "class2") ~ "creation_class",class%in% c("class3","class4") ~ "uploading class")]
table_patterns <- table_patterns[, source := case_when(message%in% c("adapting new values within system|data wrangling and transformation in system") | class %in% c("class5", "class6") | pattern %in% c("user1 has uploaded new text") ~ "text_uploading",class %in% c("class7") ~ "alt_class",TRUE ~ "self_search"), by = .(class, pattern, system_type,source,message_type)][,
```

As you see I create table_patterns  and then transform it three times. How could i do it in one process. Without editing it three times? No data example is needed, its about code syntax, so no need for data example.

Comment: From your code, you are creating 3 columns in those 3 lines.

Comment: @akrun yes. i want to do it in one line. and write it in more efficient way, if possible

Comment: In the 2nd and 3rd line, your grouping is same, but in the last it is different.  So, it is not clear how you can write in one line

Comment: @akrun i think that grouping in 2 and 3 is not necessary. only last one matters

Comment: @akrun i edited question

Comment: Thanks, in your code, you are also using the grouping variables in `j` i.e. `class`.  So, without a small example, it is not clear

Comment: @akrun class is just another column. im interested in uniting all these code lines on one. without data.table i would use pipes, but what to use here?

Comment: If you just wanted to pipe with data.table, `table[, pattern := stringr::str_extract(LOG_MSG, "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+")
      ][, pattern := coalesce(stringr::str_extract(pattern, "^create new|regulate values"),pattern), by = .(class, pattern)
   ][, system_type := case_when(class%in% c("class1", "class2") ~ "creation_class",class%in% c("class3","class4") ~ "uploading class"), ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `data.table`, the `:=` modifies in place.  So, there is no need to assign the output (`<-`) to another object.  The chaining of multiple arguments can be done as

```
library(data.table)
table[, pattern := stringr::str_extract(LOG_MSG, "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+")
      ][, pattern := coalesce(stringr::str_extract(pattern, 
         "^create new|regulate values"),pattern), by = .(class, pattern)
      ][, system_type := case_when(class%in% c("class1", "class2") ~
           "creation_class",
      class%in% c("class3","class4") ~ "uploading class"), by = .(class, pattern)
      ][, source := case_when(message %in% 
           c("adapting new values within system|data wrangling and transformation in system") | 
                class %in% c("class5", "class6") | 
                pattern %in% c("user1 has uploaded new text") ~
                   "text_uploading", 
                class %in% c("class7") ~ "alt_class",
         TRUE ~ "self_search"),
         by = .(class, pattern, system_type,source,message_type)][]
```

Comment: and how to ungroup table? tell me please

Comment: @french_fries  with `data.table`, it wouldn't create any group attribute.  So you don't have to do that